# Columnwise count in R

Tags: r, count

I am new to R. Tried searching for the answer but haven't got it as yet.I am sorry if somebody has already asked it.

```
Name1   Name2   Name3   Count_Var
A   B   C   3
D   E   F   3
G   H       2
I           1
J   K       2
    L   M   2
N   O       2
```

I have three variables Name1,Name2 and Name3 in my dataframe. I want to introduce another variable i.e. count_var which would be the count of elements of Name1, Name2 & Name3.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is counting over rows, or counting elements in a row, and not in columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution can be:

```
df$Count_Var = apply(df, 1, function(x) length(which(x==1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical matrix i.e. create one where there are no blank elements (assumed that it is `""` for blank)

```
df1$Count_Var <- rowSums(df1[1:3]!="")
df1$Count_Var
#[1] 3 3 2 1 2 2 2
```